# Why does php use camelCase

Tags: naming-conventions

I wonder why do languages like PHP use camelCase for function naming and
languages like c# use PascalCase for function naming

is this simply determined in this way 
or is there another reason

Thanks

Comment: PHP doesn't use camel case. PHP uses whatever. It's a mess. Furthermore, there is no strict reason why languages choose what they choose. As long as it is consistent, it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks i just wanted to know

Comment: @BartFriederichs is wrong. Coding standards PSR-1 and PSR-2 define the proper naming conventions. They are very useful when working with a team on the same codebase. If you aren't on a team, use whatever convention you prefer, as long as your IDE doesn't care.

Comment: @pbarney thanks for the PSR's, I hadn't heard from them yet. Note though that the PHP language itself is not following these recommendations. In PHP7 wil still have `bin2hex` and `strtolower`, we still have `str_replace` and `strcmp`.

Comment: Of course. The first iterations of PHP were poorly designed, IMO. The question has always been, "should we break backwards compatibility to make the language pure and pristine?" The answer has always been, "no, don't go overboard, man!"